# Deploying .NET 6 Web API and SQL Server database with a Vue.js frontend on DigitalOcean

Tags: deployment, digital-ocean

Im trying to deploy an online application with a .NET 6 Web API backend app with a database and a Vue.jg frontend. The problem that I’m experiencing is when I try to use my github repository for the beckend application I get a “no component detected” error and cannot proceed with with creating the source. I'm not sure if the setup with .NET is supported on this platform.

Comment: I also got this issue. please let me know if you have a solution.

Comment: Are you still facing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue and found a solution that worked for me. I containerized my application using Docker, which helped me to deploy the application on DigitalOcean without any issue.

The easiest way I found to containerize my application was to use the **"Container Orchestrator Support"** menu in Visual Studio. You can find more information about this process in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/overview?view=vs-2022).

After the containerization process, the error regarding **"no component detected"** disappeared, and I successfully deployed my application in DigitalOcean.

Also this helped me: [Deploy asp .net 6 application to digital ocean app](https://driesdeboosere.dev/blog/how-to-auto-deploy-an-aspnet-60-application-to-digital-ocean-app/)